# Parity of the sum of three dice's faces.

Tags: probability

What is the probability of the sum if three dice's faces being even?

Route 1: $P("All \space three \space dice's \space faces \space are \space even" or "Two \space of \space them \space are \space odd \space and \space one \space is \space even")$ and I get $1/2$, which I know is the correct answer.

Route 2: $1 - P("All \space three \space dice's \space faces \space are \space odd")$, and I get $7/8$.

Where did I go wrong in route 2?

Comment: For each $X,  P(X) = P(21-X).$  If $X$ is even $21-X$ is odd and vice versa.  For every even roll there is an odd roll with equal probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In route 2 you forgot the case of one odd and two evens.

But there is a simpler way to see that the result is $1/2$. Imagine that you throw two dice first, check the sum, and only then throw the third. It's clear that half the possible throws of the third die will result in the total sum being even, and half of them will result in the sum being odd.

Comment: In other words, if we let $N$ be the count of even faces.
$$\begin{align}\textsf{Route 1:}~&~\mathsf P(N=3 \cup N=1) ~=~ \mathsf P(N=1)+\mathsf P(N=3) &~=~& \frac 3 8 + \frac 1 8\\[1ex]\textsf{Route 2:}~&~1-\mathsf P(N=0) ~=~ \mathsf P(N=1)+\mathsf P(N=2)+\mathsf P(N=3) &~=~& \frac 3 8+ \frac 3 8 + \frac 1 8\end{align}$$